# how to set value of Input Box in Jsp

Tags: java, jsp

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

  <html>
  <form action="index.jsp">

    <body>
      First INPUT:
      <input name="firstinput" type="text" value=<%=request.getParameter( "firstinput") %>>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      <% String first = request.getParameter("firstinput");
            out.println(first); %>
    </body>
  </form>
  </html>
```

Ths is My code when Put Input tax then after Button click its set to tax and Print Tax But when I tax Input "tax" then Value set to tax in Input Box while Print correct "tax" i want to set input Box value also "tax" when I take Input "tax" after click please help

Comment: The last 3 lines description really confused me alot,Please rephrase your description,Sure will help you.

Comment: i want Set Value if we Input hello then it should set in text box hello and If Input "hello" then it should to "hello" in Input box But Currently when set Input write "hello" in input Box then it set hello while I want set Same thing

Comment: Got it Suresh atta if not then i can Explain more simply i am asking if we input text as Anil then in value field it should set Anil and if input text as "Anil" then it should set "Anil"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have both:

```
name="firstinput"
```

and

```
name="fname"
```

for the same input field!

**UPDATE:** In addition to that, change:

```
value=<%=request.getParameter("firstinput") %>>
```

to:

```
value='<%=request.getParameter("firstinput")%>' />
```

Comment: name="firstinput"  for this

Comment: Thanx actually i wanted this

Comment: but i wanted for each special charter like if we Input 'Anil' then it should set 'Anil' or if setinput +Anil+ then it should set +Anil+

Comment: Works fine! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Its working fine dude

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index.jsp" method="get">

            First INPUT:            


            <input name="firstinput" type="text" value=<%=request.getParameter("firstinput") %>>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <%
            String first = request.getParameter("firstinput");
            out.println(first);

             %>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please Enter "Atul" is it set to "Atul" in input field please check